# Handler of dynamically added linkbutton is not getting called

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm generating in my back code LinkButton but for some reason the handler that I'm attaching to the link button is not been called.

**GetRegionName() get called in the pageload event**

apsx page code:

```
<div class="GeneralFontShape">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblDynamicRegion" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
 </div>
```

VB.Net Code:

```
Public Sub GetRegionName()
    Try
        Dim dba As New DBAccess()
        Dim dt As DataTable = dba.GetEFolderUserLocations(m_User.SessionID, m_User.UserID, m_User.CompanyCode)
        If Not dt Is Nothing Then
            Dim RegionName As String = Nothing
            Dim RegionID As String = Nothing
            Dim output As String = Nothing

            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows()
                RegionName = dr.Item("RegionName").ToString()
                RegionID = dr.Item("RegionID").ToString()

                '# Creating instance of LinkButton
                Dim lb As New LinkButton()
                lb = New LinkButton()
                lb.Text = RegionName '# LinkButton Text
                lb.ID = RegionID.ToString() '# LinkButton ID's
                lb.CommandArgument = RegionID.ToString() '# LinkButton CommandArgument
                lb.CommandName = RegionName '# LinkButton CommanName
                AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf lb_Command '# Create Handler for it
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lb)

                Dim lbl As New Label()
                lbl.Text = "<br>"
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl)

            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub lb_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    Try

        Dim lnk As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    RetrieveAllQueryStringParams()

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GenerateControls()
        GenerateDataSets()
        'GenerateLabels()
        GenerateLinks()
        'GenerateOther()
    End If
End Sub
```

The function GetRegionName() is been called in GenerateControls()

Comment: What does the event lb_Command look like, and what does your Page_Load look like?

Comment: I edited my question so you can see it

Comment: What is the function of the linkbutton supposed to do? Just wondering the exact reasoning for checking `CommandEventArgs` instead of just using `e As EventArgs`. I'm comparing your code to my own working code and just can't see the relevance, but I could easily be missing some pertinent detail in the process.

Comment: Okay so the reason I created the link button is to populate the RegionName from my DB and for each RegionName I want to create a link button. so far it's creating it on my web page but when I click on one of the link button the page actually been load again like it's doing postback.  The function link button is supposed to set focus on the region in Google Map on the right side of my page on the user click on it.

Comment: Postback is normal behavior when clicking a link button. How is the Google Map function called? Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Google Maps development.

Comment: I just wonder if you can help me out with the handler that not been called. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Problem solved by looking at this hope it can help others: pohttp://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/command-event-not-firing-on-programatically/381174st